# Accessing Mac OSX or iOS Core Data SQLite Tables via R

Tags: ios, r, macos, sqlite, core-data

I have a iOS/OSX app that I built that stores Core Data in a SQLite database.  I can access the data with the apps Liya and DB Browser for SQLite.  I am trying to access the data via R, but get no tables found.  The table I need to access is shown in the photo.  I am trying to select all the data from ZACTIONFIGURESALECOREDATA for analysis, but cannot figure out how to access any table.  The tables seem not to be accessible from R the way I am connected.  Suggestions?

[image: DB Browser for SQLite]

or Liya

[image: Liya]

When I run the following, I don't get any errors:

```
# load packages
if (!require(DBI)) {
 install.packages("DBI")
}
library("DBI")

starWarsCon = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Containers/com.LightningBrainGames.MyToyBox-Utilities/Data/Library/Application Support/MyToyBox_Utilities.sqlite")

# get a list of all tables
allTables = dbListTables(starWarsCon)
```

Although `AllTables` contains `character (empty)`

Running

```
p1 = dbGetQuery( starWarsCon,'select * from ZACTIONFIGURESALECOREDATA' )
```

Gives

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
no such table: ZACTIONFIGURESALECOREDATA
```

I also tried

```
dbGetQuery(starWarsCon, "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
```

Which returns

```
[1] type     name     tbl_name rootpage sql     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I just did a `find ~/Library/Containers -name "*sqlite"` to enumerate any I had locally and randomly selected 2 of them and all `RSQLite` functions plus even `src_sqlite()` (which is rly `src_dbi()`, now) all work. I realize that's not super-helpful, but have you checked permissions? What happens when you run `str(file.info("/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Containers/com.LightningBrainGames.MyToyBox-Utilities/Data/Library/Application Support/MyToyBox_Utilities.sqlite"))`?

Comment: And, you were doing so well redacting the username `jasongloor` ;-) Back on topic: my hope was that the file was just inaccessible (permissions-wise) but you can see the file. I'm using 2.0 of `RSQLite` and 0.7 of `DBI`. Can you dblchk your versions (just so I'm positing advice from same versions)

Comment: DBI 0.7 and RSQLite 2.0. `str(file.info("/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Containers/com.LightningBrainGames.MyToyBox-Utilities/Data/Library/Application Support/MyToyBox_Utilities.sqlite")) 'data.frame': 1 obs. of 10 variables: $ size : num 0 $ isdir : logi FALSE $ mode :Class 'octmode' int 420 $ mtime : POSIXct, format: "2018-02-03 08:38:57" $ ctime : POSIXct, format: "2018-02-03 08:38:57" $ atime : POSIXct, format: "2018-02-03 21:37:38" $ uid : int 501 $ gid : int 20 $ uname : chr "xxxxxxx" $ grname: chr "staff"`